# harris corner points coordinates

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I am new in opencv so could you help me to find coordinates of points that detected by  harris using following code?

source image is `img`

i want to store coordinates of corner points in matrix `S`

```
Mat S;
dst = Mat::zeros( img.size(), CV_32FC1 );
cornerHarris( img, dst, 7, 5, 0.0001, BORDER_DEFAULT );
dst = Mat::zeros( img.size(), CV_32FC1 );
cornerHarris( img, dst, 7, 5, 0.0001, BORDER_DEFAULT );

// Normalizing
normalize( dst, dst_norm, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_32FC1, Mat() );
convertScaleAbs( dst_norm, dst_norm_scaled );

 for( int j = 0; j < dst_norm.rows ; j++ ) {
     for( int i = 0; i < dst_norm.cols; i++ ) {
         if( (int) dst_norm.at<float>(j,i) > thresh ) {
             S.at<int >(j,i)= (int) dst_norm.at<int>(j,i);
         }
    } 
}
```

Comment: take a look at [cornerHarris_Demo.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/TrackingMotion/cornerHarris_Demo.cpp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the points coordinates in a `Nx2` matrix, where the first column is the `x` coordinate, and second column is the `y` coordinate.

You can declare `S` as an empty `CV_32SC1` matrix like:

```
Mat S(0, 2, CV_32SC1);
```

(or you can even leave `Mat S;`, since the type is determined by the first `push_back`).

Then you can append the coordinates. Inside the `if` statement, add:

```
// Create a matrix for the point
Mat pt(1,2,CV_32SC1);
pt.at<int>(0, 0) = i;
pt.at<int>(0, 1) = j;

// Add the point to S
S.push_back(pt);
```

---

Note that it can be more straightforward to use `std::vector<Point>` to store points. In this case, you can declare `Svec` as:

```
std::vector<cv::Point> Svec;
```

and in your `if` statement you'll have:

```
Svec.push_back(Point(i,j));
```

or

```
Svec.emplace_back(i,j);
```

If needed, you can convert the `vector<Point>` to a `Mat` like:

```
Mat Z(Svec); // Creates a 2 channels matrix, Nx1
Z = Z.reshape(1); // Creates a 1 channel matrix, Nx2
```

Comment: Mat pt(1,2,CV_32SC1);
pt.at<int>(0, 0) = i;
pt.at<int>(0, 1) = j;

Answer (score 0):

```
Mat pt(1,2,CV_32SC1);
pt.at<int>(0, 0) = i;
pt.at<int>(0, 1) = j;
```

`i` , `j`  in ur code will be values of i,j counters. 
I need to put coordinates of harris corner points

Comment: What do you think I and j are if not x and y coordinates?